# Un job de laravel se ejecuta bien en postman pero no funciona desde otra app

Tags: laravel, api, email, postman, queue

Tengo una api que envía correos electrónicos usando un job, la pruebo en postman y funciona perfectamente pero cuando la llamo desde un botón (en otra aplicación llamando a la api) no ejecuta el job. ¿alguna sugerencia? Gracias

```
public function prueba()
{
     $datos['pass'] = 'FnJKfkuG';
     $datos['nombre'] = 'Gordon';
     $datos['ruta'] = 'myapi.test/validate-email/jQZSPFSZLuBqAdQofxtV5Bw2TK4ZcrNmoxFFR5ZvgGM48gHyKcxv7y6jHBaZhHIF';
     $datos['correo'] = 'abc@gmail.com';
     $data['title'] = '¡¡Hola!!';
     $data['body'] = 'Texto aquí.';
     SendEmailJob::dispatch('', $datos,'','', $datos['correo'],'bienvenido');
}
```

SendEmailJob usa una funcion llamada sendMail en un helper:

```
sendMail($this->mailto, 'Confirmación de solicitud', 'newRequest', $this->data, 'mi correo');

function sendMail($mailTo, $subject, $view, $data, $from)
{
    try {
        Mail::to($mailTo)->send(new SendMail($from, $data, $view, $subject));
        return sendResponse('Ok');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        Log::debug($e->getMessage());
        return sendExceptionError('Error 2',$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

La clase SendMail finalmente es la clase mailable.

funciona en postman con la ruta: myapi.test/api/v1/test, se ejecuta el job y se envía el correo electrónico

pero cuando llamo a esta ruta desde otro proyecto, no funciona

Intento depurarlo usando logs, cuando uso postman funciona de maravilla pero cuando lo uso en un botón tiene un error: Expected response code "250" but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required" entonces, el job no se ejecuta.

Es muy raro no entiendo porque

Gracias
​

Comment: pon el código de `SendEmailJob`

Comment: Hola @javdromero. SendEmailJob solo tiene una linea de codigo incluida arriba  sendMail($this->mailto, 'Confirmación de solicitud', 'newRequest', $this->data, 'mi correo');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUCIONADO: Copié la configuración de correo electrónico del archivo .env y config/mail.php en el proyecto api a .env y config/mail.php en el proyecto de la aplicación. No sé si es la mejor solución o la correcta, pero ahora funciona. Gracias a todos por las respuestas.